# unable to finishTransaction in app purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have a problem which either allows me to download apple hosted content or finishTransaction but not both;

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark SKPaymentTransactionObserver methods

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray     *)transactions
{
for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
{

    switch (transaction.transactionState)
    {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:

                NSLog(@"Purchasing");

            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:

            NSLog(@"Transaction State Purchased");

            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]startDownloads:transaction.downloads];




            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:

            NSLog(@"Transaction State Failed");

            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];

            [self failedTransaction:transaction];

            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:

             NSLog(@"Transaction State Restored");

            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] startDownloads:transaction.downloads];
            buyButton.enabled = NO;
            [buyButton setTitle:@"Purchased"
                       forState:UIControlStateDisabled];

            //break;
        default:
            break;

    }
}
}


- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedDownloads:(NSArray *)downloads;
{
for (SKDownload *download in downloads) {

    switch (download.downloadState) {

        case SKDownloadStateFinished:

            NSLog(@"Completing transaction-B");

            [self processDownload:download];
            [queue finishTransaction:download.transaction];
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:download.transaction];
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];

        break;

        case SKDownloadStateActive:


            NSLog(@"%f", download.progress);
            NSLog(@"%f remaining", download.timeRemaining);

        break;

        default:
        break;


    }

}
}

-(void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{ //checked!!

NSLog(@"Complete transaction");

//[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:transaction];
buyButton.enabled = NO;
[buyButton setTitle:@"Purchased"
           forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
}
```

generally the code works fine;
the product is displayed
I can select to buy 
login request

then as per the code above the download works and is processed (moved to the Document directory).

However, if i finishTransaction in updatedTransactions then the download will not occur. (makes sense!)

if I call [self completeTransaction:transaction] to finishTransaction from updatedTransactions I get the same.

If i neglect to call completeTransaction (as per the code) then content is downloaded but then I can't seem to call finish transaction.

where/how do I call finish transaction?

so close but so far!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling finish transaction too early and my download was not able to finish.